# Issue with combined use of WatchOS connectivity and watch scene segues

Tags: ios

I have a working watchOS app that uses watch connectivity, however whenever I try to add a segue and a secondary interface controller the watch no longer has a connected session. The issue really seems to stem from the segue. Deleting the segue makes it work again...

What am I not understanding about how segues work and how can I use segues and still have the connection working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up your watch connectivity session in your extension delegate on your watch and in your app delegate on the phone. This will allow you to use the default session in any interface controller that you create by calling WCsession.default()

Comment: In the end I put all the connectivity function in the delegate,  for some reason it never worked right in the interface controller. I'm still unsure as to the mechanics of it and why it wasn't working...

Comment: It wasn't working in the second interface controller because you created the session in the first interface controller. Doing this makes the session only accessible from the first controller, not the entire project